# Why does pyinstaller executable change the format and resolution?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, resolution

I've been surfing through the internet and have failed to find the answers I'm looking for. I am new to python and asking questions here, but anyways, I am running windows 10, and my script uses tkinter as the GUI module. Whenever I run the script through the command prompt (or IDE) I get this: [Image via IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCykd.png)

Whenever I run pyinstaller executable, I get this: [pyinstaller executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ89N.png)

As you can see, the executable changes some of the geometry of the widgets and makes the image blurry. How do I fix this on my computer, and how do I account for this across various windows supported hardware?

Comment: Weird, i think its more of a windows scale issue, search google for 'blurry text in gui windows 10' and see if anything helps

Comment: Well I found the issue! Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: Just answered the question. Big thumbs up to you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, glad you found your solution, you will be able to mark it as the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is with windows and can be corrected by right clicking on the executable in the file window and following these steps: https://www.ghacks.net/2020/09/14/how-to-fix-blurry-text-in-programs-on-windows-10/